I have a problem uploading my project to heroku: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
(I'm working with Java)
I want to upload my site online. I'm using Heroku for this job. But I got this error and I ask them to help me:
Generally, you would be able to see the cause of app crashes in the logs preceding the H10 App Crash errors, specifically the logs between Starting process... and State changed from starting to crashed. Oftentimes, these errors are related to the application's code rather than the Heroku platform.
May 14 10:44:33 rrcb heroku/web.1 Starting process with command 'java -Dserver.port=35728 $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/RRCB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
May 14 10:44:33 rrcb heroku/web.1 State changed from starting to crashed
May 14 10:44:33 rrcb heroku/web.1 Process exited with status 1
May 14 10:44:33 rrcb app/web.1 Create a Procfile to customize the command used to run this process: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
May 14 10:44:33 rrcb app/web.1 Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
May 14 10:44:33 rrcb app/web.1 Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
May 14 10:44:33 rrcb app/web.1 no main manifest attribute, in target/RRCB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
May 14 11:05:55 rrcb heroku/web.1 State changed from crashed to starting
I'm not sure what to do can you help me?
Here is my pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>RRCB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RRCB</name>
    <description>RRCB</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- That looks a bit weird !! -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
<!--            <version>3.0.4</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>3.11.0</version>-->
<!--        </depe  ndency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.mypackage.MyClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->
<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                <version>3.0.7</version>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->

<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                <version>3.7.0</version>-->
<!--                <configuration>-->
<!--                    <source>1.8</source>-->
<!--                    <target>1.8</target>-->
<!--                    <verbose>true</verbose>-->
<!--                </configuration>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->

            <!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                <version>3.0.7</version>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
